# How to handle invalid date string input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project is relatively straight forward. I am attempting to create a web-scraping tool that retrieves a random event from any given wikipedia article for a given date. The format of the URL is: `url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{month}_{day}"` where the month is the full name of the month followed by the day.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

What I'm trying to achieve specifically here is that if an **invalid date** such as June 31 or Feb 30 were input, then the function below stops and returns a `Please provide a valid date` as its output without an error message.

**Attempted Solution:**

I've tried this with an `if` statement mapping a set of months to a set of dates but it's pretty wonky, as shown bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    
month = 'January'
day = '99'
    
url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{month}_{day}"

thirty = [*range(1,31)]
thirty = [str(x) for x in thirty]
thirty_one = [*range(1,32)]
thirty_one = [str(x) for x in thirty_one]
twenty_nine = [*range(1,30)]
twenty_nine = [str(x) for x in twenty_nine]


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

def wikiscraper():

    events = []
    
    if (month == set(['April','June','September','November']) and day != set(thirty))| \
    (month == set(['January','March','May','July','August','October','December']) and day != set(thirty_one))| \
    (month == set(['February']) and day != set(twenty_nine)):
        return print("Please provide a valid date")
    
    else:    

        for li in soup.select("h3 + ul > li"):
            if (h2 := li.find_previous("h2")) and (h2.find(id="Events")):
                date, event = li.text.replace("–", "-").split(" - ", maxsplit=1)
                events.append((date, event))
            
        events = pd.DataFrame(events)
        cols = ['year','event']
        events = pd.DataFrame(events)
        events.columns = cols
    
        pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 300
        events['combined'] = 'On this date in the year'+' '+events.year+' '+events.event
        events = events[['combined']]
        return events.sample()

wikiscraper()
```

which returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-b89d9001cf84> in <module>
----> 1 wikiscraper()

<ipython-input-129-2c547a995093> in wikiscraper()
     18         cols = ['year','event']
     19         events = pd.DataFrame(events)
---> 20         events.columns = cols
     21 
     22         pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 300

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5150         try:
   5151             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5152             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5153         except AttributeError:
   5154             pass

pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    562     def _set_axis(self, axis: int, labels: Index) -> None:
    563         labels = ensure_index(labels)
--> 564         self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
    565         self._clear_item_cache()
    566 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    224 
    225         if new_len != old_len:
--> 226             raise ValueError(
    227                 f"Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old_len} elements, new "
    228                 f"values have {new_len} elements"

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

I also tried it with `assert` which works, but I want to keep it clean without an assertion error and just have a printed output requesting a valid date. The `if statement` I'm sure is not a very "pythonic" way of doing it either, although getting to run with the desired output is the bigger priority.

My ultimate goal is to simply get the function to stop and `Please provide a valid date` if the string input is not compatible with real dates.

**edit. The solution was simple**

```
    if (month in set(['April','June','September','November']) and day not in set(thirty))| \
    (month in set(['January','March','May','July','August','October','December']) and day not in set(thirty_one))| \
    (month in set(['February']) and day not in set(twenty_nine)):
        return print("Please provide a valid date")
```

just use `in` and not `==` User Timus to the rescue on a dumb mistake.

Comment: This seems like an [X Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), that's for starters. Secondly, you *really* should ditch that custom date handling and use a built-in [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module and, for example, catch a `Value Error`.

Comment: Since `month` is  `'January'` the expressions `month == set([...])` etc. are _always_ `False`. The same goes for `day != set(thirty)` etc.. You are comparing strings with sets. I guess you want to check for membership, i.e. mean `month in set(...)` and `day not in set(...)`? (I agree with the other comment: Using `datatime.date` would be better.)

Comment: @Timus Dude you got it! I actually came to the realization after I posted this but had to do some errands, but doing what you suggested worked.